# Node JS Backend Not Displaying Result on the Frontend of Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, api, frontend, backend

I have a project that is using Node JS as the backend communication to the Angular Frontend. I have buttons on the angular frontend for the 4 API Actions (Get, Post, Put, Delete). My backend is successfully calling my external API, executing one of the 4 API Actions when the corresponding button is clicked, and printing the results in the console. However, the results are not showing up on the angular frontend. Is there anything I need to check for to see why this is not working? I am not sure where to start with it.

HTML Code:

```
<form #documentNum="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getDoc(documentNum.value)">
            <div class="input-group mb-3 spacing">
              <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Document Number" aria-label="Recipient's username"
                aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="getDoc" name="getDoc" ngModel>
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="GET" id="submit">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="_method" value="PUT">
                <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="_method" value="DELETE">   
                <input class="btn btn-warning y-btn" type="submit" value="POST" id="submit">
                              

              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-lab5',
  templateUrl: './lab5.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lab5.component.css']
})
export class Lab5Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/'
  //constructor(){}
  list:any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getDoc(data: any) {
    this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL + 'db/' + (data.getDoc - 1)).subscribe(res => {
      this.list = res;
      console.log(this.list);
    })
  }

}
```

Node JS (for get verb):

```
app.get('/db/:number', async function (req, res) {

  await client.connect();
  const database = client.db("lab5");
  const coll = database.collection("players");
  var players = coll.find({}).toArray().then(() => {

   
    coll.find({}).toArray(function (err, symbols) {
      if (!err) {
        var output;
        var num = req.params.number;
        console.log(num);
        var all = symbols[num].data;
        

        res.send(all);

      }
      // client.close();
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: It's unclear what results, or why you expect them to show up. Do you do anything with the response? Do you make additional requests to find out what's changed? Without a [mre], we're just guessing - you need to do some debugging.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just updated my question if you would like to take a look.

Comment: You don't seem to actually use `list` anywhere, so maybe that's it. Give an actual MRE - what were you expecting to happen here?

Comment: I have an input box that prompts the user for a number. I have to read that number (which I do in the form in HTML and the typescript function) and get the document from my MongoDB collection that is that index (the number the user inputted). Right now, the data from the document is appearing on the console log but not on the frontend.

Comment: Because you _do_ `console.log` it, but _don't_ render `list` anywhere. So why's that surprising?

Comment: In my node js file, I do res.send. Shouldn't that mean it should display that data?

Comment: All that does is add data to the response. That's **clearly working**, because you're showing it in the `console.log` and assigning it to `this.list`. But then you **never use `this.list`**. So to answer _"Shouldn't that mean it should display that data?"_ - no.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question but where would I render list? in the typescript function or in node?

Comment: On the _template_, assuming you want to see it in the Angular frontend. It's not at all clear from your question how or where you're expecting it to show up, maybe on a different "page" entirely (for which Angular has a router). I'd strongly recommend running through https://angular.io/tutorial/ to get to grips with the basics of the tool you're trying to use.